# How to change the UI language in Google Drive?

Tags: user-interface, google-drive, locale

There is currently no option to change the UI language in Google Drive.

Is it possible to change it somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shutdown GoogleDrive
Go to **Start** and start typing **system environment** and then click on **Edit the system environment variables**

[image]

Click on **Environment Variables**

[image]

Click the bottom **New** button

[image]

For Variable name enter **LANG** and for Variable value enter **en_US**.

[image]

Confirm everything with OK.
Start GoogleDrive.

Comment: In Windows 8 this window is under Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings

Comment: Who's issue is this? Microsoft's or Google's?

Comment: This does NOT work for Google File Stream. Google developers supposed to be the TOP ones, but seems to be pathetic, users are unable to select the app language!