# Change Google Drive UI language on local windows install

Tags: language, user-interface, google-drive

I've installed Google Drive locally on my Windows machine. I'd like to change the menus language to English. How can this be done? I can't find it in the preferences...

Comment: We need more information about the system in question to answer this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the UI language in Google Drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/522070/how-to-change-the-ui-language-in-google-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to change the UI language in Google Drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/522070/how-to-change-the-ui-language-in-google-drive)

In Windows 8 this window is under Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings